# Integration tests custom HTTP client in net core

Tags: c#, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to use custom HTTP client in integration tests?

Instead of getting client instance from TestServer

```
Client = Server.CreateClient()
```

to use my own implementation. Smthng like:

```
Client = new DSClient(Server.BaseAddress.AbsoluteUri, Credential);
```

When I do so i'm constantly getting 404. WAIDW?

Comment: Are you calling the base constructor in your inherited class?

Comment: @john Nope. The point is my Client is a wrapper and it doesn't provide same methods as HttpClient

Comment: If Server.CreateClient() is part of the self-hosting functionality, then you'll need to pass it as the base HttpClient into your wrapper. The self-hosting functionality operates entirely in memory, I believe.

Comment: Obviously that doesn't mean that you need to expose the same methods as the client provided, but I think you have to use it in your wrapper methods. Whare are you trying to achieve? Could it be done by creating your own DelegatingHandler?

Comment: @john yep, you saved me. 

`Server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
TestClient = Server.CreateClient();
Client = new DSClient(TestClient);`

Had to modify DSClient class with new constructor, but it works. Thanks

Comment: @John If you write an answer than I'm happy to vote it up. Your suggestion works for me too, so I can use my custom HttpClient in my tests.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and in my situation I can not use the existing HttpClient because I need to modify the HttpClient when initializing it. So my solution is to create a server and test it using my own HttpClient.

```
using(var server = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(new List<string>().ToArray())
    .UseEnvironment("Test")
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
    })
.Build())
{
    server.Start();
    var client = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000")
    }
    var resp = client.GetAsync("test/testme").Result;
}
```